# Loop to execute multiple instructions in bash, which start from the top if one instruction fail

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I am looking at an efficient way to do this.

I have various commands that I need to execute in sequence; the second can't run if the first fail and so on.

I did loop through them; but the loop has to go through each command, which is not what I need to do.

For example, if there are 3 commands: a, b and c; a run all the time, b run only if a ran successfully, and c has to run only if b ran successfully, but if b failed once, it has to start all over from a

```
LOOP *****************************
until a; do
  echo "a failed, retrying"
  sleep(3)
done
until b; do
  echo "b failed, need to start all over"
  b_failed=1
  break
  START FROM THE BEGIN OF LOOP ***************
done
until c; do
  echo "c failed, need to start all over from a"
  c_failed=1
  break
  START FROM THE BEGIN OF LOOP ***************
done
.... OTHER INSTRUCTIONS
LOOP *****************************
```

I tried to use a regular loop, but the break will exit from the sub loop, and won't start from the begin.
I would like to enter this main loop, execute the first operation until it pass, then execute the second; if it fail it start from the top of the loop, without run all the other commands and so on.
Although I can't seem to find the correct way to do so, unless I bloat the logic with a ton of if-else check every command.

Is there a clean way to do so, in few lines?

EDIT: wrote while instead of until; made the correction

EDIT2:
Thanks a lot for the solution!
Although it has to be modified, since I was not able to run it as it is: the if is missing the fi to terminate the command, and missing the "then" statement. I was not able to run the do inside the if; so this is what is working for me:

```
while true; do
    until a; do
        echo "a failed, retrying"
        sleep(3)
    done
    if [ ! b ]; then
        echo "b failed, need to start all over"
        continue
    else
        c
    fi
    if [ ! c ]; then
        echo "c failed, need to start all over from a"
        continue
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: I think you might be confused about what `while` does. `while` is a loop, and currently your first section is going to keep echoing "a failed, retrying" every 3 seconds as long as `a` is successful. It will only move on to `b` when `a` fails.

Comment: Couple of things as 8bittree mentioned above: 1. you have to check for if a, b or c are fail in your while statements. 2. put your whole code in another while clause that checks a custom variable that indicates if everything executes as needed in the process of execution of your commands. If not, set it accordingly in the internal local while statements and check its value between the internal while statements. If the value indicates there was a problem in the above command, make a `continue` line to start over from beginning.

Comment: a && b && c; will execute b and c only if the previous command ran successfully.

Comment: Once a, b, and c have all complete successfully, do you want to run them all again in a loop, or are you simply trying to ensure that they all run once, in order, with no failures in between?

Comment: Sorry, wrote it quickly and instead of until I wrote while. I did try to simplify the case. I need basically a way to implement the main loop (the LOOP section), and how to exit from the sub loops starting from the beginning

Comment: @Squeezy: trying the concatenate solution now.

Comment: @8bittree: I need to run the whole sequence once; the loop is needed to guarantee that each command run at least once; and that no failures happen.

Comment: @Mike: I did think about point 2, although the issue is that I need a check for each of the commands. If they are 3, no problem, but imagine a scenario with 20 or more commands; this could get bad pretty easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple solution, as partly mentioned by Squeezy:

```
until a && b && c; do
    :
done
```

`&&` is the logical and operator. It does short circuit, so the expression to the right is only evaluated when the expression to the left is true.

The return value of the complete `&&` expression (or chain of `&&`s) is the result of the last evaluated expression. So if any one of the three commands here fails, the ones after will be ignored and the `until` will see a `false` and enter it's body, do nothing (`:` is just a no-op to fill the body of the loop), and loop back to the test condition `a && b && c` again. If all three succeed, then the `until` will see a `true` and end.

So this is good for simple case, but not good if you want to print those status messages. It's possible with `||` (the logical or) and `{ }`, but it's going to be very messy.

This is better if you want to do something extra when a command fails, such as echo status messages:

```
while true; do
    until a; do
        echo "a failed, retrying"
        sleep(3)
    done
    if [ ! `b` ]; then
        echo "b failed, need to start all over"
        continue
    fi
    if [ ! `c` ]; then
        echo "c failed, need to start all over from a"
        continue
    fi
    break
done
```

`continue` returns to the start of the enclosing loop. Putting a number after it returns to the start of the enclosing loop `n` levels up. Though that's not necessary here, because they're inside `if`s instead of loops. Incidentally, `break` will similarly take a number and break out of `n` enclosing loops.

The `a` section could also be an `if [ ! a ];` instead of the `until` loop, if you'd prefer to keep things looking the same. You'd need to add a `continue` in that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never had to face such logic; so it was interesting to figure out how it actually works. In the old days you would use goto and labels, but that was a hellish way to do things. So if I concatenate the commands, if a pass and b fail, it will start from the beginning? Because if it doesn't then it won;t work for me. I am trying the second approach, which is longer but seems to fit my case.

Comment: @newbiez: the second solution is roughly what I wanted you to do. The first simple solution is a bare bone, bash-y solution which will start evaluation from the beginning (from left to right). the second solution is more the general way to do it in a bash script when you need to do something if a particular command has failed.

Comment: @newbiez I added some explanation of what's going on with the first solution. I also realized that, since `b` and `c` are happening inside `if`s instead of loops, the `continue`s don't need the extra numbers, and in fact may be harmful if this whole thing is within yet another loop.

Comment: Much appreciated. BTW do I need a break at the end, after the last if statement, to get out of the main while loop? Since it is just "true"; it will go on forever, right?

Comment: @newbiez Correct, and I fixed it. You could also use a `done=false; until $done` and set `done=true` at the end if you prefer.

Comment: I am not sure why but I get an error when running the first if. There is no fi at the end of each if, als the "then" is missing; but I get an error from bash, saying "syntax error near unexpected token 'do' ". I believe you can't use do without a loop condition first

Comment: @newbiez This is what I get when I don't check my work closely enough. I fixed that as well. I also realized that you may need to wrap your commands in backticks ( ` ) inside the if conditionals so that it tests the return code, rather than the name.